# Kendo mobile Scrollview. Reset vertical scrollbar

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am using Kendo UI mobile Scrollview to switch between views by swiping.But my problem is that, the vertical scrolling remains on the same position from the previous view. I want to move the vertical scroll to top when a view is switched.

There are no built in methods to do so. Anyone can suggest me a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The overflow scrolling in the pages, which I guess you're using, has nothing to do with Kendo UI Mobile and you should handle it yourself by resetting scrollTop.

Other than that you can use separate Scroller widgets on the ScrollView pages which will avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  id="yourview" data-role="view">
<div id="scroll-view" data-role="scrollview"  data-init="init" data-changing="changing" data-change="change"  data-init="false" >
</div>
</div>
function init(){
//on scrollview event - init :
scrollParentView = $("#scroll-view").data("kendoMobileView").scroller;
}
function changing(){
//on scroll view  event- changing :execute before page changes
scrollParentView.reset();//resets scroll on page change
}
function change(){
//on scroll view  event- change :execute after page changed
scrollParentView.reset();//resets scroll on page change
}
```